# Unexpected output with array function call by adress

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

We currently learn about pointers in combination with arrays in C/C++ and have to implement some function, for which we have a given function call.
The objective is to print out the array values by calling the function with the array adress. The output is not what was expected.

I tried printing the the array values with `&` and `*` as well as with none of those.

```
void ausgabe1D_A(double (*ptr1D)[4]){
    int i{0};
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << *ptr1D[i] << "  ";
}

int main()
{
    double ary1D[4] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

    ausgabe1D_A(&ary1D);
}
```

I expected the output to be:
    1.1  2.2  3.3  4.4

Instead I got:
    0x61fdf0  0x61fe10  0x61fe30  0x61fe50 (with and without &)
    1.1  9.09539e-318  0  0 (with *)

EDIT: Sorry if that wasn't clear, but we have to call the function with `&ary1D`. We are trying out different ways and your ways are coming up in the exercise in following functions but for now we need it with the `&`-Operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although others provide a possible solution, I will try to explain why your code fails. Expression `double(*ptr1D)[4]` refers to a pointer to an array of four elements (doubles). To get values, you should firstly dereference the pointer and only then print out its n-th value, as follows:

```
void ausgabe1D_A(double (*ptr1D)[4])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::cout << (*ptr1D)[i] << " "; // <-- note the parenthesis
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is what I've been looking for! Did i get it right, that I had a pointer pointing on an array which essentialy is a pointer and that's why the first value of the array was printed correctly while the others were not?

Comment: @xCuse The problem was probably that `*ptr1D[i]` points to base of array + i * length of whole array. Hence, the out-of-bound accesses. [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3fb27b1634f1728)

Comment: An array decays to a pointer to the first element. So `ary1D` decays to a pointer to a double. Going the other ways `double (*ptr1D)[4]` is what a two dimensional array decays to. Your input (with the `&` operator) is a 1x4 two dimensional array. `*(ptr1D[i])` [parents for emphasis] then prints the first double of each row. Since your input only has one row the rest are garbage, out of bounds array access.

Answer (score 2):

When you reference an array by its name, you are referencing it by its pointer, so you function argument is wrong. It should be like

```
void ausgabe1D_A(double *ptr1D, size_t size){
    int i{0};
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << ptr1D[i] << "  ";
}

int main()
{
    double ary1D[4] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

    ausgabe1D_A(ary1D,4);
}
```

Here is a picture of the memory of a `short integer` array for example

[image]

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry that i didn't make it clear but I need to call the function with `&ptr1D`

Comment: @XCuse, no!  ```ary1D``` is a pointer. it's like ```&(ary1D[0])```. Arrays are pointers to an array of the type.

Comment: Thank you, we already learned that an array is nothing else than a pointer to an adress where the array element 0 is saved in and that `ary[i] is equal to *(ary+i)`. Nonetheless I had to use the given parameter `&ary1D`. And sorry it shoudl have been `&ary1D` not `ptr1D`.

Comment: If using &ary1D is mandatory, then you can reference it like (*ary1D)[i].

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that arrays can decay into pointers, so you'd write something like

```
#include <iostream>

void ausgabe1D_A(double* ptr1D){
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << ptr1D[i] << "  ";
}

int main()
{
    double ary1D[4] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};
    ausgabe1D_A(ary1D);
}
```

The way this works is that the pointer `ptr1d` is essentially the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer! Unfortunately we have to call the function like this `ausgabe1D_A(&ary1D);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for way to  pass using & operator. Here you go.

```
void print( int (*arr)[4])
{
    int *d = *arr;
    for(int i = 0 ;i <4 ; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<d[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    print(&arr);

}
```

Let me know if you found it hard to understand.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot!